# Same method on dynamic select option in Angular, Is this possible?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a dynamic array that has an onChange method on the select option.  When I select the option the method works but when I add a new array and select the new option the first array resets. Here is my array:

```
  <ng-container formGroupName="envelopeRequest">
    <button (click)='initDocument()'>Add Document</button>
    <ng-container formArrayName="documents">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="let control of documents.controls; let comIndex=index"
      >
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="comIndex">
          <div class="row justify-content-start mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              {{comIndex}}
              <input
                type="hidden"
                id="fname"
                name="fname"
                formControlName="documentId"
              />
              <label for="formFile" class="col-form-label">File:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="file"
                id="file"
                name="file"
                formControlName="name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-container formArrayName="documentFields">
            <ng-container
              *ngFor="let skillIndex of documentFieldsIndexes(comIndex);"
            >
              <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Category:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
                    <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value"  (change)="changeCategoryList($event)">
                      <option selected>Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let c of categoryList">
                        {{c.name}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>

                <label class="col-auto col-form-label">Sub-Category:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex + 1">
                    <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value" (change)="changeSubCategoryList($event)">
                      <option selected>Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let s of subCategoryList">{{s.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>
                <label class="col-auto col-form-label">List:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex + 2">
                    <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value">
                      <option selected>Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let name of typeList">{{name}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

I'm assuming it's because both select options are using the same method now.  Here is a snippet of my ts code:

```
 changeCategoryList(category: any) {
    this.subCategoryList = this.categoryList.find(
      (cat: any) => cat.name == category.target.value
    ).subCategoryList;
  }

  changeSubCategoryList(subList: any) {
    this.typeList = this.categoryList
      .find((cat: any) => cat.name == this.selectedCategoryList)
      .subCategoryList.find(
        (stat: any) => stat.name == subList.target.value
      ).typeList;
  }
```

Is it possible to have an index on a method? Here is a link to the full code on

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jiskqe?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your HTML, you are sharing the `subCategoryList` instance for the `documentSubCategory` select options across the `FormGroup`s in the `documents` `FormArray`.

You should create/use a separate instance for each `FormGroup` to avoid overwriting the value when selecting the `documentSubCategory` in another `FormGroup`.

Using the `comIndex` to determine whether the data selection list should fall under which `FormGroup`. Your `subCategoryList` will be a multi-dimensional array that holds the respective data for the sub-category data selection according to the `comIndex` sequence. The concept is the same as the `documentType` selection.

```
subCategoryList: Array<any[]> = [];
typeList: Array<any[]> = [];

changeCategoryList(category: any, comIndex: number) {
  this.subCategoryList[comIndex] = this.categoryList.find(
    (cat: any) => cat.name == category.target.value
  ).subCategoryList;
}

changeSubCategoryList(subList: any, comIndex: number) {
  let selectedCategory = this.documentFields(comIndex).get('0')?.get('value')?.value;
      
  this.typeList[comIndex] = this.categoryList
    .find((cat: any) => cat.name == selectedCategory)
    .subCategoryList.find(
      (stat: any) => stat.name == subList.target.value
    ).typeList;      
}
```

When adding the `document`, you should add a new empty array to both `subCategoryList` and `typeList` arrays.

```
newDocument() {
  this.subCategoryList.push([]);
  this.typeList.push([]);

  return this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    documentId: new FormControl(''),
    documentFields: this.fb.array([]),
  });
}
```

For the HML, you need to provide the `comIndex` to the `changeCategoryList` and `changeSubCategoryList` methods. And retrieve the respective select options with `subCategoryList[comIndex]` and `typeList[comIndex]`.

```
<select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value"  (change)="changeCategoryList($event, comIndex)">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of categoryList">
    {{c.name}}
  </option>
</select>

<select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value" (change)="changeSubCategoryList($event, comIndex)">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let s of subCategoryList[comIndex]">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>

...

<select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let name of typeList[comIndex]">{{name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-o5swqd?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thank you @YongShun.  I now have an understanding of what needs to be done going forward.  Much appreciated.